# How to create Work item with template using API

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to create a Work item with template, how to create it? is there any API? I am able to create Work item using following link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0

As show in image, while creating Work item we select template, same thing I want to achieve using API while creating Work item.

[image]

Comment: Review the documentation more carefully. There is an entire API section for templates.

Comment: @DanielMann You mean https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/templates?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1 or that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item-template?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1?

Neither is about creating Workitems from templates...

Answer (score 0):

The general gist is to retrieve all the field-values defined in the template via a GET on the templates-endpoint. Take these values, patch the values from the to-be-created-workitem and create a workitem form that via POST.

So there is no endpoint doing a create-a-workitem-from-that-template-kinda-thing.